# Rename list of files with his last characters

Tags: r

I want to rename my data frame with the last characters of his actual name.
How can i do this please ?

```
#Importing file 
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.csv2(temp[i]))
```

an exemple of file imported is:

```
XXX__Xxxx_Xxxxx__XXX-X.csv
```

i want to change it to:

```
XXX-X.csv
```

How can i make loop to read a specific XXX-X.csv please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe we could use `str_sub` from `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)
str_sub(str1,-9,-1)
```

Output:

```
[1] "XXX-X.csv"
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `trimws` and specify the `whitespace` to match characters (`.*`) till the one or more underscore (`_+`) to remove those

```
trimws(str1, whitespace = ".*_+")
[1] "XXX-X.csv"
```

There is no need for a loop as these are vectorized functions

```
trimws(temp, whitespace = ".*_+")
```